# Jekyll/Liquid Templating: How to group blog posts by year?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm rewriting my blog to use Jekyll. Jekyll uses the Liquid templating language so it makes it a little more difficult to learn how to customize.

I'd like to group my list of blog posts by year. How would I write the Liquid code to be able to do this?

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <li><!-- display post year here (but only once, per year) --></li>
  <li>
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It involves or involved capturing and is really horrible. http://mikerowecode.com/2010/08/jekyll_archives_grouped_by_year.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to break it down by year, here's the code:

```
{% for post in site.posts  %}
    {% capture this_year %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
    {% capture next_year %}{{ post.previous.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
    <h2 id="{{ this_year }}-ref">{{this_year}}</h2>
    <ul>
    {% endif %}

    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>

    {% if forloop.last %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        {% if this_year != next_year %}
        </ul>
        <h2 id="{{ next_year }}-ref">{{next_year}}</h2>
        <ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to break it down to year and months it can be achieved like this:

```
{% for post in site.posts  %}
    {% capture this_year %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
    {% capture this_month %}{{ post.date | date: "%B" }}{% endcapture %}
    {% capture next_year %}{{ post.previous.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
    {% capture next_month %}{{ post.previous.date | date: "%B" }}{% endcapture %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
    <h2 id="{{ this_year }}-ref">{{this_year}}</h2>
    <h3 id="{{ this_year }}-{{ this_month }}-ref">{{ this_month }}</h3>
    <ul>
    {% endif %}

    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>

    {% if forloop.last %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        {% if this_year != next_year %}
        </ul>
        <h2 id="{{ next_year }}-ref">{{next_year}}</h2>
        <h3 id="{{ next_year }}-{{ next_month }}-ref">{{ next_month }}</h3>
        <ul>
        {% else %}    
            {% if this_month != next_month %}
            </ul>
            <h3 id="{{ this_year }}-{{ next_month }}-ref">{{ next_month }}</h3>
            <ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is only a matter of where do you make the cut on the loop.

Comment: can this be made to work with site.categories.xxx ?

Answer (score 66):

It can be done with much, much less Liquid code than in the existing answers:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign currentdate = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
  {% if currentdate != date %}
    <li id="y{{currentdate}}">{{ currentdate }}</li>
    {% assign date = currentdate %} 
  {% endif %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This will return exactly the HTML specified in your question:

```
<li id="y2013">2013</li>
<li><a href="/2013/01/01/foo/">foo</a></li>
<li id="y2012">2012</li>
<li><a href="/2012/02/01/bar/">bar</a></li>
<li><a href="/2012/01/01/baz/">baz</a></li>
```

---

However, this is not the optimal solution, because the year numbers are "only" list items as well.
It's not much more Liquid code to put the year into a headline and to begin a new `<ul>` for each year's posts:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign currentdate = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
  {% if currentdate != date %}
    {% unless forloop.first %}</ul>{% endunless %}
    <h1 id="y{{post.date | date: "%Y"}}">{{ currentdate }}</h1>
    <ul>
    {% assign date = currentdate %}
  {% endif %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% if forloop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The generated HTML:

```
<h1 id="y2013">2013</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="/2013/01/01/foo/">foo</a></li>
</ul>
<h1 id="y2012">2012</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="/2012/02/01/bar/">bar</a></li>
<li><a href="/2012/01/01/baz/">baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**You can also group by month and year instead** (so that the headlines are `February 2012`, `January 2012` and so on).

To do this, you just need to replace `date: "%Y"` *(in the second line of both above examples)* by `date: "%B %Y"`.
*(`%B` is the full month name, see the [documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/additional-filters#date))*

Comment: This is great, thank you!  One note is that you don't create the final </ul> for the last group.  So, after the for loop, you'll want to do something like {% if site.posts.size != 0 %}</ul>{% endif %} after the for loop.

Comment: Or right before the loop ends, {% if forloop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the other solution didn't work for me as my posts aren't necessarily  sorted by date, but that this one did! Thank you!

Comment: This is a great post. I managed to adapt it to my situation. I am confused about how it works though - could anyone update this answer with comments in the Liquid code?

Comment: Is it possible to display the number of posts besides year and month?

Answer (score 40):

These previous solutions are fantastic but luckily in late 2016, [Jekyll added a `group_by_exp`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/5513) filter that can do this much more cleanly.

```
{% assign postsByYear =
    site.posts | group_by_exp:"post", "post.date | date: '%Y'" %}
{% for year in postsByYear %}
  <h1>{{ year.name }}</h1>
    <ul>
      {% for post in year.items %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}-{{ post.date }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation can be found on the [Jekyll Templates page](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/).

Comment: Is it possible to do this with site.data rather than posts? For example I have 10 sets of data all with a data variable which fall within 3 dates that I want to loop like this. Or is it only possible with nested liquid loop? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could group any array using the same technique:

{% assign groupedData = site.data | group_by_exp: "data", "data.yourVariable" %}

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. If you're on a newer version of Jekyll, this is definitely the route to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The doc can be found here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#group-by-expression

Answer (score 10):

Some solutions above are very complex but then as [@Trevor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028205/trevor) pointed out that we can levarage Jekyll's `group_by_exp` filter. Also I liked the solution but what I needed was grouped by Year and then inside that list grouped by Month. So, I tweaked it a little bit.

```
{% assign postsByYear = site.posts | group_by_exp:"post", "post.date | date: '%Y'" %}
    {% for year in postsByYear %}
      <h1>{{ year.name }}</h1>
      {% assign postsByMonth = year.items | group_by_exp:"post", "post.date | date: '%B'" %}

      {% for month in postsByMonth %}
        <h2>{{ month.name }}</h2>
        <ul>
          {% for post in month.items %}
            <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}-{{ post.date }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>

      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Variation of [Ankit R Gadiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7203958/ankit-r-gadiya)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115360). The inner `for` loop was displaying the html code. I needed to de-indent it to get it to properly render the markup. I also added the post's excerpt:

```
{% assign postsByYear = site.posts | group_by_exp:"post", "post.date | date: '%Y'" %}
{% for year in postsByYear %}
  <h1>{{ year.name }}</h1>
  {% assign postsByMonth = year.items | group_by_exp:"post", "post.date | date: '%B'" %}

{% for month in postsByMonth %}
<h2>{{ month.name }}</h2>
<ul>
  {% for post in month.items %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      <br>{{ post.excerpt }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
      {% assign year = post.date | date: "%Y" %}

      {% if year != prev_year %}
        <h3>{{year}}</h3>
      {% endif %}

      <li>
        <span>{{ post.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}</span>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      </li>
      {% assign prev_year = year %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
{% for post in site.posts  %}
  {% capture this_year %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}

  {% if forloop.first %}
  <h2 id="{{ this_year }}-ref">{{this_year}}</h2>
  <ul class="posts">
  {% else %}
      {% if this_year != last_year %}
      </ul>
      <h2 id="{{ this_year }}-ref">{{this_year}}</h2>
      <ul class="posts">
      {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

    <li>
      <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }} &raquo;</span>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>

  {% if forloop.last %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}

  {% capture last_year %}{{ this_year }}{% endcapture %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did not much like the other answer so here's an alternative for you. Basic logic: Display year/month only if it "new":

```
{% assign var currentYear = 0 %}
{% assign var currentMonth = 0 %}
{% for post in site.posts  %}
{% capture year %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture month %}{{ post.date | date: "%B" }}{% endcapture %}

{% if currentYear != year %}
<div>
  <h2>{{ year }}</h2>
</div>
{% assign var currentYear = year %}
{% endif %}
{% if currentMonth != month %}
<div>
  <h3>{{ month }}</h3>
</div>
{% assign var currentMonth = month %}
{% endif %}
<p>{{ post.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```