# (Bootstrap/Jekyll) Post list defined by year and month in separate columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, liquid

I would like the format of my list of posts to follow something similar to this, where the year and month are separate columns:

[image]

[I know how to specify the year and month for a list of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086284/jekyll-liquid-templating-how-to-group-blog-posts-by-year), but my implementation ends up looking like this:

[image]

Does anyone have tips on how to do this using columns or similar? I'm guessing I need to change the Bootstrap template and incorporate the Liquid data within it, but I can't quite visualise how it would be done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Liquid, but in order to use columns in bootstrap, create a grid structure and tag it with CSS classnames, here's one way to do it:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <h2>2014</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <h3>February</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h4><a href="#">My amazing post about something boring</a></h4>
            <h4><a href="#">My boring post about something amazing</a></h4>
            <p class="tags">
                Tagged: <span>java</span>  <span>proxy</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the [docs for the bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

---

[<kbd>**Click Me, I'm The Demo Button!**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/fAHsTSVmOqLaP4oBrffb?p=preview)

Comment: That demo button is seriously amazing. Thanks for an example of how to define the columns.

I'll figure out the Liquid myself at some point.

Comment: sure, no problem. i didn't notice any reference to liquid, just saw the tag now. please add this information in the question body.