# Pulling from specific subfolders using {% for post in site.posts %}

Tags: css, pug, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm currently working on my first Jekyll site. I have a page in which 2 seperate sections display previews of certain posts (a styled thumbnail).

What I want is for these sections to display posts from different subfolders in _site/_posts. I have organized _posts to contain two subfolders, /lesplannen and /verslagen (lesson plans and reports), each containing a bunch of articles.

My code for one of these sections is as follows (Jade formatting):

```
{% for post in site.posts limit: 4 %}
    a(href="{{post.url}}" target="_blank" style="background-image: url(assets/img/posts/lesplannen/thumbnails/{{post.thumbnail}})").lesplan-thumb
      .article-meta
        .name {{post.title}}
        .date {{ post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}
    {% endfor %}
```

And similarly for the other section. My first instinct was to change site.posts to site.posts.lesplannen and site.posts.verslagen repectively, but this resulted in the thumbs not displaying at all. I also added the categories to the front matter in the articles themselves, but this wasn't picked up either.

For clarity, what I'm trying to do is have section 1 display posts from _site/_posts/subfolder 1 and section 2 display posts from _site/_posts/subfolder 2.

What would be the right way to go about this?

Question for bonus points: The page displays 4 posts, as expected, but chooses to display post 6 through 9 of the 12 posts available. Why is this and can I specify to e.g. always display the last x posts?

For reference:
GitHub page: https://zaena.github.io/portfolio-nadine/
GitHub repo: https://github.com/Zaena/portfolio-nadine

Comment: Here's some more information that might help with the ordering problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196559/jekyll-post-order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website has several issues:

## The posts folder structure is wrong

Posts should **always** be in a `_posts` folder, they can't be inside another folder (Jekyll can display them but some functionality is lost, they are not meant to be there)

## If categories are folders, they can't start with an underscore (_)

The actual structure has categories defined as `/_verslagen`, they should be `/verslagen` and its posts inside `/verslagen/_posts`

## Having the same post in two different folders has unexpected behaviour

There are posts located in different folders, only one version should exist.

## Solution

The structure you are looking for is:

```
├── index.html
├── lesplannen
│   └── _posts
│       ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-lesplan2.md
│       ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-lesplan3.md
│       ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-lesplan4.md
│       └── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-lesplan.md
└── verslagen
    └── _posts
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag10.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag11.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag12.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag2.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag3.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag4.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag5.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag6.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag7.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag8.md
        ├── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag9.md
        └── 2016-12-10-dit-is-een-verslag.md
```

This will make posts available under each category in `site.categories.verslagen` and `site.categories.lesplannen`.

Then the code to show each category posts looks like:

```
{% for post in site.categories.verslagen %}
<p>{{post.title}}</p>
<p>{{ post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</p>
<p>{{post.thumbnail}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for post in site.categories.lesplannen %}
<p>{{post.title}}</p>
<p>{{ post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</p>
<p>{{post.thumbnail}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I get what you're saying! I will implement this and get back to you. Thank you for your detailed comment.

Comment: This worked! Both sections are displaying their respective content. Thanks for taking the time to clarify this, I understand Jekyll a bit better now :)

Comment: Just curious @marcanuy, can you find any documentation suggesting to avoid subdirectories in `_posts`, and that having the same post in two different directories has unexpected behaviour? I've tried but I can't even find the documentation for categories :P

Comment: @BilalAkil `_posts` is meant for posts only, subdirectories should be directly under other categories: `category\subcategory1\subcategory2\_posts` (not `category\_posts\subcategory1`).

Comment: Yep, that makes sense now that you've demonstrated it, but I find it strange that this feature doesn't appear to be documented. It's not mentioned in the Directory Structure/Writing Posts/Collections documentation... not sure where else to look - I just can't find it. I had no idea it actually existed until you mentioned it; I thought categories only came from YAML front matter only. All good though, thanks for teaching me about it :D

Comment: @BilalAkil look at the description of page.categories in http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables. "The list of categories to which this post belongs. Categories are derived from the directory structure above the _posts directory. For example, a post at /work/code/_posts/2008-12-24-closures.md would have this field set to ['work', 'code']. These can also be specified in the YAML Front Matter."

Comment: Oh there it is! Nice find, and thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got them displaying separately:

**`index.html`**

```
---
---

<p>Posts in dir-a:</p>

<ul>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        {% assign first_dir = post.path | remove_first: "_posts/" | split: "/" | first %}
        {% if first_dir == 'dir-a' %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}: {{ post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<p>Posts in dir-b:</p>

<ul>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        {% assign first_dir = post.path | remove_first: "_posts/" | split: "/" | first %}
        {% if first_dir == 'dir-b' %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}: {{ post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This assumes the following directory structure:

```
/_posts
/_posts/dir-a
/_posts/dir-b
```

Should be nice and easy to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Hi Bilal, thanks so much for your reply.
Unfortunately, my page insists on displaying posts 6-9 from dir_a despite specifying dir_b. For simplicity's sake I've uploaded a screenshot of the code: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/3IG2aCr.jpg).

Can you spot any errors I've made? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Ok I can't see anything obvious from the screenshot, so I'm not sure why it's behaving that way. Quick sanity check: did you rebuild the site since changing the code? If you have, then could you push your site to a development branch on your GitHub repo so I can check it out and try and replicate the issue? Also, what version of Jekyll are you using (`jekyll --version`)?

Comment: After some trial-and-error, I got the indentation right (which was important since I'm using Jade). However, the articles from dir_a now show up fine, but the ones from dir_b don't show at all. The code is identical. Do you have any insight?

Comment: My current build is now on GitHub! My Jekyll version is 3.3.1. The code can be found in _jadefiles/sections-verslagen and _jadefiles/secions-lesplannen respectively. The former is the one that is currently working.

Comment: That's the same version as me, so it should work at some point :P I'll look into it, but in the meantime here are some debugging tips: you can output the variables after assigning them like so: `{{ first_dir }}`, or check out the intermediate steps: `{{ post.path | remove_first: "_post" }}`. Keep messing around with this and you may realise what's going wrong.

Comment: Hey Bilal, the main issue was with my folder structure as Marcanuy pointed out in the other comment. Regardless, cheers for helping out!

Comment: Glad you've got it working :) I actually think the breaking point at the end of our chain was that the files in the `lesplannen` directory used the .MARKUP extension. "MARKUP" was written in the documentation as a placeholder to be replaced depending on which markup you're using (i.e. .html, .md, .etc..). That being said, all of @marcanuy's suggestions would help you have a better and more maintainable project overall.