# Jekyll, how to display images in a folder by date?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am creating a website gallery. There is such a structure:

```
my site
  artworks
    caty1
    caty2
```

It is necessary to display the photos in page of a given category (`caty2` or `caty1`) by creation date. 
Actually, how to realize using Jekyll and Liqiud? 
Or is there a more appropriate structure for this?

Comment: You may be insterested in this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41662022/1165509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with liquid you can [filter/sort](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#sort) an array but any of its elements attribute that you want.

in your case you need to create [datafile](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) (in *yml*, *csv* or *json*) representing a collection of photos, and each photo should have a `date` attribute (along with a name, src, ...).

then in the `layout` that generate a `caty` page you'll have some thing like:

```
{% assign sorted-photos = site.data.photos | sort: 'date' %}
<ul> <!-- list of sorted photos -->
{% for photo in photos %}
  <li> <img src={{photo.src}} alt={{photo.name}}></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

the photos collection would be a `photos.yml` file located in `_data` directory with a structure similar to:

```
- src = assets/img/p1.jpg
  date = 10-01-2017
  name = cute cat
  category = cats  # if you need to filter by category ?   

- src = assets/img/p2.jpg
  date = 12-01-2017
  name = grumpy cat-2
  category = cats 

- src = assets/img/p3.jpg
  date = 10-11-2016
  name = cool dog
  category = dogs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you please add to answer, how can I create a collection of photos with Jekyll in `_config.yml` in my example?

Comment: if you're familiar with json, you can consider each element (starting with an important `-` ) as an obeject, and the whole file as a document. each object has key/values peer.

Comment: Thank you! This is a solution... But сan't I just have a folder with pictures and display all by date in a simple cycle? It seems, I must set each picture as a parameter in `photos.yml`, not too comfortable?

Comment: you can, but you'll need to have access to the `date` attribute of the file, and be able to use it to filter the photos, and i suppose that you'd like to have more control over which photo displayed in which category, hence the additional attribute.

Comment: the other solution require that you create a [ruby plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators), to filter the photo directly from the folder and include them in the template the way you want..

Comment: I use gulp instead... May be in this I can resolve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133300/discussion-between-yaitloutou-and-vostoksisters).