# Octopress archives as dropdown categories aside alike Google Blogging

Tags: octopress

I have had gone through plugins which could do a cloud based categories tag asides: refer:`https://github.com/ctdk/octopress-category-list` and also the good known working **Top Categories**: refer: `http://time.to.pullthepl.ug/blog/2012/8/20/octopress-top-categories-plugin/` but both of these do not serve my purpose.

My purpose would be to use the categories aside like the default way which Google Blogger ships, how do I achieve this and customize this to the requirements?

A screenshot of concept (like year-wise with drop down):

[image: Blog Archive]

Comment: Did you tried that http://stackoverflow.com/a/19104574/1548376 ?

Comment: I did not try this one yet. Are their any live examples if this worked? I am very new to Jekyll support, where do I put this code in order to customize. I read docs and it says SASS handles all the CSS and customizations.

Comment: The second example from link provided in my comment can be pasted in any file index.html, _includes/postSideBar.html, or whatever you name it. Here you have your posts sorted by year and month. Finding a way to style and animate your menu is another question. You have to do some r&d.

Comment: but this still won't be an aside but rather an example shown in this site `http://mikerowecode.com/archive.html` which means an extra page is being created rather the archive drop down list to appear on aside. This somehow brought some hope. I am wondering how do I integrate the drop down into aside?

Comment: Read the doc http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes