# sorting filtered liquid data

Tags: sorting, csv, jekyll, liquid

With reference to this question:[Jekyll/Liquid Templating: How to group blog posts by year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086284/jekyll-liquid-templating-how-to-group-blog-posts-by-year/20777475#20777475)

I have implemented the answer by Christian Specht which in my case returns a list of goal scorers from a csv file stored in my `_data` folder and it works perfectly.

**However, how do I then return these in order of highest-lowest?**

At the minute, the goalscorers are just returned in the order they appear in the csv file.

My code:

```
<h2>Top goal scorers</h2>
<table>
 {% assign goalscorers = site.data.members | sort: 'sortby' %}
 {% for goalscorer in goalscorers %}
  {% if goalscorer.goals > "0" %}<tr><td>
   {{ goalscorer.surname }} </td><td>{{ goalscorer.goals }}</td></tr>
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The resulting html:

```
<h2>Top goal scorers</h2>
<table>
 <tr><td>Moore </td><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Cromwell </td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Gould </td><td>3</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Dowsett </td><td>6</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Whalley </td><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Tindall </td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Jones </td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've done it, I needed to change the assign line to:

```
{% assign goalscorers = site.data.members | sort: 'goals' | reverse %}
```